# Latex document contains only \section{}?

Tags: lists, enumerate, titlesec

I want to typeset a document with desired output such as:

```
1. blah blah ...
   blah blah  ....


2. blah blah ...
   blah blah  ....


3. blah blah ...
   blah blah  ....
```

That is simply numbered output (with text wrap and aligned), with each item taking the whole page width. One way I tried is to redefine \section{} command by:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\titleformat*{\section}{\normalfont}
\begin{document}
\section{blah}
\section{blah}
\section{blah}
\section{blah}
\section{blah}
\section{blah}
\section{blah}
\section{blah}
\section{blah}
\section{blah}
\section{blah}
\end{document}
```

So my document ends up with \begin{document} \section{...} \section{} ...\end{document}.
Apparently, this confused the layout processing, it tries to put all section in ONE page and ONE page only, no matter how many sections command I have.

I don't like more obvious `enumerate` environment because its indention of each item, I'd like each item to take the whole page width like `section` did.

Can someone tell me what am I doing wrong and how best to get the results? TIA

Edited to add example doc.

Comment: The indentation of enumerate isn't fixed it is setable via various parameters (probably most easily using the `enumitem` package)

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Please help us to help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: I don't understand the connection between `\section` and enumerates in this OP

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I added sample doc to illustrate. `enumitem` looks promising, will try. The other reason I preferred to customized `\section` command is because vim folding feature allow me to fold/unfold such headings. But apparently it didn't work as I expected.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are two simple solutions with `enumitem`:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage[showframe, nomarginpar]{geometry}

\usepackage{enumitem}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\begin{enumerate}[wide=0pt]
\item \lipsum[2]
\item \lipsum[3]
\end{enumerate}

\begin{enumerate}[align=left, labelwidth=1em, leftmargin=\dimexpr\labelwidth+\labelsep \relax]
\item \lipsum[4]
\item \lipsum[5]
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

[image]